# Running a java jar with eclipse swt dependencies with maven-dependency-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, eclipse-plugin

I'm making an eclipse plugin that I also want to make it work command line. As normal the usual problem is encountering the eclipse dependencies in command-line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Layout
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

Now I know there is an eclipse FAQ for this problem however here is a bit different. I'm using Maven for build with the maven-dependency-plugin to add jars I need from other project to this jar as dependencies:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Copy non-Eclipse plugins to target/dependency so that may be referenced 
                for runtime use. -->
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- seems the line below is needed otherwise every second run the 
                            copy-dependencies fails , link to bug : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393978 -->
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The dependencies in my Manifest file looks like this:

```
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ 
 lib/jcommon-1.0.23.jar
 lib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar
 lib/jfreechart-1.0.19-swt.jar
 lib/jfreechart-1.0.19-experimental.jar
 lib/swt.jar
 target/dependency/my.first.package.jar
 target/dependency/my.second.package.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: my.package.Main
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader

Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/jcommon-1.0.23.jar,
 lib/jfreechart-1.0.19-experimental.jar,
 lib/jfreechart-1.0.19-swt.jar,
 lib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar,
 lib/swt.jar

Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 my.first.package;visibility:=reexport,
 my.second.package;visibility:=reexport,
 ca.odell.glazedlists,
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.swt
```

As you can see I added an swt.jar to a lib inside my project and am referencing it there as to have all my dependencies inside my jar.

Still I get the above error when I try to run it command line as if the swt.jar isn't there.

What am I missing?

Comment: An Eclipse Plugin which should work on command line as well? You know that you need an OSGi container for the eclipse plugin?

Comment: I had no clue. It's actually just a tool where you load a local file and it creates a graphical representation of it based on words. I wanted to make a separate main class (the plugin is an eclipse view) which opens an SWT Window where you have buttons and menus. It works if I'm running it from eclipse as a normal java application, it just doesn't work when I'm trying from command line after my build. If I really need an OSGI container for this, please tell me more on how can I make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make an Eclipse plugin command-line friendly, the best thing is to have the plugin also define an Eclipse application that you can then invoke from command-line: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_application%3F

Comment: Not as eclipse independent or stand-alone as I envisioned it but a brilliant alternative nonetheless. Thanks!